# Only one thread at a time c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a task with a huge amount of input data (video). I need to process its frames in the background without freezing the UI and I don't need to process every frame.

So I want to create a background thread and skip frames while background is busy. Than I get another frames from video input and again.

I have this simple code now. I worked. But can it cause troubles and may be there is a better approach?

```
public class VideoProcessor{

 bool busy=false;

 void VideoStreamingEvent(Frame data){
  if(!busy){
   busy=true;
   InvokeInBackground(()=>{
    DataProcessing(data);
    busy=false;
   });
  }
 }

}
```

Comment: As it is...it won't work (in a reliable way). `busy` flag has to be `volatile`. That said...if it works for such (simple?) localized task IMO there is no need to make things more complicate than this.

Comment: It is not clear from question what you want. You want to execute `VideoStreamingEvent` in only one thread? If so what would you expect to happen when another thread is trying to execute it at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But can it cause troubles and may be there is a better approach?

If the `VideoStreamingEvent` method never executes concurrently on multiple threads, then this will work fine if you simply add `volatile` to the `busy` field declaration.  It may, in practice, *appear* to work well enough without it, but that behavior is not guaranteed.

If it is possible for `VideoStreamingEvent` to be invoked on multiple threads, then you will need some synchronization around where you read and write the `busy` field.

Comment: "you simply add volatile"

Thank you, it solves that problem which I was worried about. VideoStreaming occurs only in IO thread so it can't be executed twice at a time.